# How to count total magazine pages correctly for sending info to printer?

Tags: print-production

I need to send a magazine to printer and I need to provide total number of pages including cover. Inside pages are 100, does this mean that I should say 102? Or cover counts as 4 pages, outside and inside? This is also what I need to calculate size for spine.

The pages that are like introduction pages after opening cover, are these two going to inside cover spread?

Comment: You should ask them for specifics. I can only guess what they are asking and how they do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

104, One sheet have two pages. front cover is two pages and back cover is two pages. In the magazines world (with ads on them) covers are usually counted as 4 pages. So when you say "on the third page of cover" you mean second to last page.
 Those pages are usually not counted toward TOC so you start counting from the 3 page.
If you want your introduction pages to be on a spread you need to start them on the left side. So either on the second page of cover OR second page of actual magazine leaving you two empty spaces.

Calculation from printer should look like this for 68 page magazine:
Inside, 64 pgs.
Paper :Matt DC White, 130 g/m2
Prepress :Impo
print  : front CMYK, back CMYK (it's 4+4)

Cover, 4 pgs., 29,7 x 42,0 cm open
Paper: Matt DC white, 250 g/m2
Prepress :  Impo
Print  :front CMYK + 1 color, back CMYK + 1 color (all 4 pages have also spot color, if only first and fourth page had some other print it would be front CMYK + 1 color, back CMYK)